# Fade in/out a TextBlock in a Windows Store Application [XAML/C#]

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

can someone explain me how can I add a fade in and a fade out animation to a textblock when I load a form in a Windows Store application?
I tried the WPF method but it didn't work...
Thank you :)

Comment: Try this link for your question [fade text out, change it, and fade it back in][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221674/how-do-i-fade-text-out-change-it-and-fade-it-back-in

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for (or what "WPF method" didn't work), but with this resource:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
```

invoked from `OnNavigatedTo` you'll get a fade-in effect (here on a specific instance called textBlock.)  Obviously, you can adjust the duration and easing function to your liking - and perhaps generalize for use across various controls.

```
var f = this.Resources["Storyboard1"] as Storyboard;
if (f != null) f.Begin();
```