# Fade in/out programmatically a Circle in a Windows Store Application

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, c++-cx

I want to animate in and out multiple `EllipseGeometry` in a Windows Store Application using either C# or C++/CX.

I need to do this programmatically because I have an indeterminate number of `EllipseGeometry` to show each time I execute this animation.

Let's say just for making it more concrete that I need to display those circles inside a `Grid`.

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid" Width="500" Height="500">
</Grid>
```

**Note:** There are some [answers using XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532501/fade-in-out-a-textblock-in-a-windows-store-application-xaml-c) but I really need to do this programmatically.

Comment: You can set up the animation in code as well. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br210490

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you convert XAML code to C# code?

Something like this:

```
var storyboard = new Storyboard();

var timeline = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
{
    KeyFrames = new DoubleKeyFrameCollection
    {
        new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(0),
        new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(1, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 4)))
    }
};
storyboard.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, timeline);
```

Comment: Are you sure the constructor is right? `new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(0)`